# update google chrome on fedora

Tags: fedora, chrome, dnf

I am trying to upgrade chrome on my fedora 30 install.
Currently it is stuck on "Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)"
I've removed it and reinstalled I am using this repo:

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
skip_if_unavailable=True
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
enabled=1
enabled_metadata=1
```

and then running:

`dnf install google-chrome-stable`

says it has installed it:

```
Installed:
  google-chrome-stable-76.0.3809.100-1.x86_64
```

but when I open chrome I still get version 66

Any idea what could be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the google chrome config directory and now it is using the latest installed version:

```
rm .config/google-chrome -rf
```